# Incorrect work documentation example. Near protocol

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

I created a smart contract on a testnet and everything worked great. But when I uploaded the hosting build I ran into an error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [-32700] Parse error: Failed parsing args: missing field `account_id`
    at json-rpc-provider.js:329:31
    at async parcelRequire.register.e.exports.default (exponential-backoff.js:7:15)
    at async b.sendJsonRpc (json-rpc-provider.js:304:15)
    at async b.query (json-rpc-provider.js:116:13)
    at async $2a31d1ee984c816f$export$bcca3ea514774656.viewMethod (near-wallet.js:71:26)
    at async $dad545c909cfec2d$var$updateUI (index.js:36:67)
```

I tried to do the same with the examples from the documentation. A similar error is thrown by the "Counter" example.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without the code, but it is common to see that calling a function developers forget that they should pass arguments as an object with the named fields instead of positional arguments:

```js
near.send_message({ account_id: accountId, message: message });

// NOT!
near.send_message(accountId, message);
```